# Question about ldap in dart, can we create aqueduct API with ldap authen?

Tags: api, flutter, dart, ldap, aqueduct

Im newbie in flutter and code, Im using Aqueduct to create API. Now i want to use ldap server to authen my app, i search about dartdap and it can run good in flutter app, but how to create an API with ldap authen in Aqueduct dart ? can sb help me

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is:

- Your Flutter application collects the users credentials (username and password)
- The flutter application passes those credentials in a REST call to the Aqueduct backend
- The Aquaduct backend makes an LDAP bind to the directory server using the credentials. If the BIND suceeds, you know the user has authenticated OK. You can create a session for them in Aqudeuct (probably a authentication filter - see the Aquduct documentation)